# GSMMO: Outlook 2013 ► GMail ► SPAM ► Inbox ► Sent

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, outlook

When I transfer e-mails from Outlook 2013 to GMail via GSMMO, some of my sent e-mails end up in the spam folder. I can move them to the inbox with "no spam". How do I get them from there into the sent folder? Do I really need to use IMAP? `X_X`

Comment: It also looks like that only the last complete conversation is transferred to GMail and therefore attachments from the first e-mail are missing. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gmail and Outlook mailboxes work very differently.
While Outlook has folders and allows to add any email to the sent folder, Gmail has views and labels.
Users can't add emails to `Sent` because it is a view that contains all emails where the Mailbox owner's email address can be found in the `From` field.

Workaround:

1. In Outlook create a custom folder (i.e. name it as `Outlook Sent`)
2. Move the content of the `Sent` folder to the new custom folder.
3. Migrate your email to Gmail

Result:

- There will be a label in Gmail and all the emails in your new custom folder will have that label
- Gmail's `Sent` will include all emails that were sent from the primary email address by the Gmail's mailbox owner.

Related

- [How can I delete a message from inbox without deleting it from sent mail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/23880/88163)
- [How to clean up Sent Mail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/84099/88163)

Comment: Google, seriously? So they developed a workflow that sucks? Why? I mean, some emails end up in the sent folder and some don't, LOL.

Comment: @qräbnö As it's implied in my answer, Gmail doesn't have folders.

Comment: Um, yeah? As Goethe already knew: names are sound and smoke. I used the word folder above, but don't worry, I know what a view is.

Comment: I can do your Workaround directly in Gmail. Still OMG.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the current situation (thanks to Rubén), I have drawn the following flow chart.

[image: Alphabet fail]

Comment: A solution that must be made BEFORE: Google for "Preventing Messages from Being Automatically Tagged As Spam, Gmail". Still WTF.

Comment: Why downvote? =) The workaround by Rubén does not solve this problem. X_X